# JavaScript Timing with CSS timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, delay

consider this CSS property:

```
.front{
transition: left 2s;
left : 0px;
}
```

and this JQuery function :

```
var delay = 5000;
setTimeout(function(){
$('.front').animate({left: '1300px'}, { duration: 500});
,delay}
```

Now the duration is 0.5 second .
Delay is set to 5 seconds .
Transition timing is 2 seconds .

I have done lots of attempts to figure out who wins the war of timing, but i couldn't.

could you help me and tell me what really goes on when the script runs ?

EDIT : I added the initial position property in the css class ; forgot to add it tho .

Comment: What, exactly, are you asking here?

Comment: Using CSS transition with JavaScript animation results in unexpected/bad effects.

Comment: @DA the last line is my question .

Comment: @undefined that explains a lot of the strange results i had .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script:

- waits for 5 seconds
- then animates the position of the element with a class of .front over a half second

Based on what your showing us, the CSS doesn't really do anything. Note that CSS transitions aren't the same as jQuery animations.

UPDATE:

An example based on my comments:

```
.front{
    left: 500px
    transition: left 2s;
}

.front.animate {
    left: 0px;
}

var delay = 5000;
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.front').addClass('animate');
,delay}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9q8sL/1/

Comment: what about the transition property ? do you mean that it gets ignored ?

Comment: Based only on what you are showing us, it's not ignored, it just doesn't do anything. A CSS position transition needs a start position and an end position. Your CSS has neither. You are animating via jQuery instead.

Comment: If you want to use jQuery but animate vis CSS transition (which is a good idea as you can leverage hardware acceleration) then what you probably want to do is set up all of your animation logic in CSS classes. Then use jQuery to simple add and remove said classes to trigger all the animations.

Comment: sorry, I should have noted in my example that i put that line that defines its original position .

Comment: no , not like your example ; Which is a very good idea , i think i'm going to use it tho :)